# Batch Scripting for SQL Developer, need help organizing and displaying the data

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a script using SQL:

```
spool c:\temp\output.log
set echo on 

SELECT OBJECT_NAME 
  FROM DBA_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
   AND OWNER = 'DWBATCH'
GROUP BY = 'OBJECT_NAME'
/
exit
```

I was able to receive the required tables but now I am having trouble organizing these tables within the one heading `OBJECT_NAME`. I have 383 rows selected. Is there a way to display everything under one heading (`OBJECT_NAME`), instead of having each table separated as displayed in the image?

[image: output]

Comment: Most of the SQL\*Plus [`set` options](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve039.htm#SQPUG059) also work in SQL Developer. One of those is `set pagesize`, which controls how often the headers are repeated.

Comment: How would I input this, if you don't mind me asking. I am still getting the same results I simply added this into the script

Comment: You just add `set pagesize 500` (or any number higher than the number of rows you expect) before the query. I'd do it before the `spool` but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: set pagesize 500
spool c:\temp\output.log
set echo on 

SELECT OBJECT_NAME 
  FROM DBA_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
   AND OWNER = 'DWBATCH'
/
exit

It should work, but i still get the same results. Maybe because it is sql developer?

Comment: No, that works in SQL Developer. Unless there's something weird in a really old version; which version are you running?

Comment: I am currently running, sql developer- 4.0.3.16.84-x64, thank you very much for the assistance so far.

Comment: Works fine in version 4. Are you sure the file is being recreated and you aren't just looking at the original version? Presumably you are running this all as a script (F5), not as individual statement. (I'll ignore for now that the query in the question is invalid, since your comment version is OK; but why `exit`?)

Comment: My knowledge in batch-scripting is pretty weak and I could try spool off instead of exit. I have one batch file that logs onto sql developer, and then is directed into the output batch file which I had included above, is there perhaps another way of doing this?

Comment: I take it back; 4.0.3 seems to default pagesize to -1 and changing it doesn't seem to do anything.But that doesn't produce your output. I'm not sure what "batch file that logs onto sql developer" means - if you're doing this from a Windows batch file (.bat), are you sure you aren't running SQL\*Plus, or whatever SQLcl was called then? Adding your batch file to the question might help.

Comment: Well yes I am running SQL Plus, here is what i have in my batch file called test.bat - sqlplus (credentials) @c:\temp\output.sql. and then it is directed to the .sql file i have above.

Comment: OK, then it should definitely work. If `output.sql` includes `set pagesize 500` then you shouldn't have repeating headers in your output.

Comment: I am trying to achieve exactly what the question related to this is achieving with the set pagesize n. I understand that maybe I need to change my output.sql file. Since it is not working as intended.

Comment: I still get repeated headings, maybe we can rewrite the output.sql file? Since i still get the values even without my sql statement which I do not understand.

Comment: Have you checked the timestamp on the file? It still sounds like you're looking at the original output.

Comment: Yeah I think I am looking at the original output, how can i check the timestamp and what does this accomplish?

Comment: Well, if the timestamp (from the command prompt, `dir c:\temp\output.log`) is from three hours ago, the file hasn't been updated. I don't know how you're checking the file itself though, maybe you opened it in an editor and haven't refreshed it. Maybe your batch script doesn't run if the file exists. No idea, sorry.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. I gained a strong sense of direction and will update when i figure this out. it has been updating, last time was 10 minutes ago.